# PHP GD PNGs cropping defect - with transparent bar on bottom

Tags: php, gd

I try to crop square PNG images with popular image helper class [claviska/SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage)

But I got strange occasion. After image was cropped:

```
$image->thumbnail(200, 200);
```

PNG image got transparent bar on the bottom -

[image: Defect after cropping]

PS
I think something wrong on GD part. 
I use mac OS X (GD "2.1.0 compatible")
And I reproduce this on Ubuntu 14.10 server (GD 2.1.1-dev)

[Original image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aug5wiszmow5s2n/56338ffd1a1da1.84006716.png?dl=0)

[Cropped image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pcpnfez3uydlq6/56338ffd1a1da1.84006716-thumb.png?dl=0)